# trying to build database for stock prices in SQLITE3 but getting this error

Tags: python, sqlite

```
#Import libraries in VSCode**   
import sqlite3
import investpy
import pandas as pd

connection = sqlite3.connect('app.db')

connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row

cursor = connection.cursor()
**#Executing database ?**
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT ID, Symbol, Name FROM Stock
""")
rows = cursor.fetchall()

symbols = [row['symbol'] for row in rows]
stock_dict = {}
for row in rows:
    symbol = row['symbol']
    symbols.append(symbol)
    stock_dict[symbol] = row['ID']
**#reading symbols from CSV file**
with open('C:/companies.csv') as f:
    companies = f.read().splitlines()
looping through all stocks?
    for company in companies:
        try:
            stock = company.split(',')[0]
            print(f"processing symbol {stock}")
            df = investpy.get_stock_historical_data(stock = stock, country='pakistan',                              
                                              from_date='01/06/2021',to_date='11/06/2021',
                                              interval = 'Daily')
            df = pd.DataFrame(df)
            df = df.reset_index(inplace=False)
            #print(df)
            Stock_ID = stock_dict[symbol]

            cursor.execute("""
            INSERT INTO Stock_Price (Stock_ID, Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Currency)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", (Stock_ID, df['Date'], df['Open'], df['High'], 
                                                df['Low'],df['Close'],df['Volume'],
                                                df['Currency']))
        except Exception as e:
            print(symbol)
            print(e)

connection.commit()
```

error

```
processing symbol ELCM
INTR
Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
processing symbol BEST
INTR
Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
processing symbol CYAN
INTR
Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
```

Comment: Why do you have `**` before your comments?

Comment: `df['Date']` is a Pandas series, not a single date. You can't use that as a value to insert into the DB.

Comment: You need to loop through the rows in the dataframe, and insert each row separately.

Comment: Would you please explain in code because I have basically finance background and working on this project.

Comment: Better would be to use `df.to_sql()` to insert all the rows of the df into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Does your csv has a header line? If yes you should skip it.
For example if you have a csv like this:

id, name

1, John

When you will try to insert in your database the first insert will take the id and the name as parameters. That will cause a type error since id would be an integer in your table definition but your are giving it a string.

Code sample:

```
import csv
with open("test.csv", "r") as my_file:

    reader = csv.reader(my_file)
    next(reader)
    for line in reader:
        # do stuff
```

**EDIT**
Can you check your table definition? Seems your are passing text. Is this correct?

Comment: He's getting the error on every line, not just the first line.

Comment: Ah could not read it properly before the edit. ty

Comment: cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stock (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Symbol TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        Name TEXT NOT NULL
    )
""")

cursor.execute("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Stock_Price (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        Stock_ID INTEGER,
        Date NOT NULL,
        Open NOT NULL,
        High NOT NULL,
        Low NOT NULL,
        Close NOT NULL,
        Volume NOT NULL,
        Currency TEXT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (Stock_Id) REFERENCES stock (ID)
    )
""")

Comment: No header in CSV file

Comment: So you need an integer in your first parameter. Is an integer in the first col in csv ? It seems that you have text there BEST e.g

Comment: Column A contains (symbols of stocks) and Column B contains (Company name)